# GeckoFX WebBrowser page height and width

Tags: c#, .net, browser, webpage-screenshot, geckofx

Does anyone know how I get the full page height and width in GeckoFX?
In the IE WebBrowser object, I can look at WebBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.
(The objective here is to take a screenshot of the entire page)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [Hindle's fork](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx) of GeckoFX, and here's how I do it:

```
var width = _browser.Document.ActiveElement.ScrollWidth;
var height = _browser.Document.ActiveElement.ScrollHeight;
```

I use this to create thumbnails of the page. Note, this gives us the size taken up by the *first* page we navigated to, not necessarily the size of the *current* page.  I get around that by using different browser instances for each page I'm thumbnailing.

Comment: John, I need to create a thumbnail of SVG document on the page. Could you elaborate on the method you use?

Comment: @YuriyGettya, It comes down to var docImage = browser.GetBitmap((uint) browser.Width, (uint) browser.Height); There are some edge cases you can check out in the code of my full HTMLThumbnailer: https://github.com/BloomBooks/BloomDesktop/blob/master/src/BloomExe/HtmlThumbNailer.cs. Note, since I wrote it, geckofx has acquired more image-related code, so I'd see if can't be done more simply now, using that. See https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-18.0/src/7c0672b60987b99ab4a0c4cdd374c0cdce438086/Geckofx-Core/ImageCreator.cs

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
BROWSER = new GeckoWebBrowser();
BROWSER.Height = 1920;
BROWSER.Width = 1080;
```

It seems working.

---

Visual Studio installed: Community 2019

GeckoFx installed: v45.0.34 (with NuGet package manager)