# Trying to Delay Code & Not Freezing Application

Tags: vb.net, geckofx

Im using GeckoFx Browser and im doing a manual scrollbar hide by making the window bigger than the screen so its pushed out. Code and idea works great but i want it to be automated now. If i press an element on the screen, activate my code and detect if scrollbar is displayed or not.

The issue is, i have it working off the `GeckoWebBrowser1_DomClick` and the issue is that my code executes before the window / elements change on the website.

I need the code to have a delay but not effecting the webpage loading or effecting (freezing) the app.

I tried using numerous answers from around SO and none worked as it kept freezing my app. I would post my attempts but sadly i removed the code and would slow me down trying to fish them out again!

If anyone can post some solutions that would be great!

My code:

```
Private Sub GeckoWebBrowser1_DomClick(sender As Object, e As Gecko.DomMouseEventArgs) Handles GeckoWebBrowser1.DomClick
        'Let page load/elements change and then do below code
        'Code here
    End Sub
```

Comment: Run your "Code Here" part in a separate thread, this will free the main thread from freezing the app

Comment: Can you provide an example code for running in a separate thread as i tried this and caused an error to popup which is: `Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Gecko.nsIWebBrowser'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{33E9D001-CAAB-4BA9-8961-54902F197202}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).` Thanks

Comment: Do you want me to give an example on multithreading i.e running method in separate thread?

Comment: You really need a [mcve] here.

Comment: I explained everything i have an issue with and what i want to achieve?

Comment: Is DomClick the correct event for you to respond to?  It seems like you really want to act when page load is complete---your problems appear to arise from trying to wait for that to happen---so perhaps there is another event that would be more appropriate?

Comment: @Craig Sadly, i went through most of the available events and domclick is the only workable one. Thing is, i have a queue button. When i click queue button, it takes about 2 second to load the available tracks.. Once they load, a scrollbar may or may not appear. I want my if statement to then kick in to detect the scrollbar. If it appears, push the app width out by 17. What happens is, domclick fires as soon as i click on a dom element and then stores my values.. I need it to wait till my tracks load, then grab the width values and execute my IF.

Comment: How is the page load happening?  Do you call out to page load code in domclick yourself?  Depending on the call sequence, maybe `Await` would do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try **Multithreading**

"Code Here" part in a separate thread, this will free the main thread from freezing the app.

```
Private Sub GeckoWebBrowser1_DomClick(sender As Object, e As Gecko.DomMouseEventArgs) Handles GeckoWebBrowser1.DomClick
    'Let page load/elements change and then do below code


      browservalue = (GeckoWebBrowser1.Width - GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollWidth) 
      'if you get the value here then pass it onto the following thread

     'Let's say Anything above this line is running in the Main Thread
     Dim work As New Thread(AddressOf MethodToRunAfterPageLoad) 'This will create a second thread
     work.IsBackground = True
     work.Start(browservalue)
     'this is how a single parameter is passed while threading
End Sub

Sub MethodToRunAfterPageLoad(value as Double) 'Running in second thread
    Size size = New Size(0,0)
    If value = 17 Then
        size = New Size((winwidth + 17), winheight)
    Else
        size = New Size(winwidth, winheight)
    End If

    BeginInvoke( Sub() 
                      Me.Size = size
                             End Sub )

End Sub
```

Comment: My issue was i needed a try catch to dump the errors it was getting, anyway. It works! Thing is, i now need a sleep in there in the MethodToRunAfterPageLoad to allow it to sleep and then do its check for scrollbar. When i use lets say `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)` it wont execute anything below it?

Comment: `MsgBox("Before")
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
            MsgBox("After doesnt get fired, i dont even see this msgbox")`

Comment: I realized its cause im getting an error which is stopping my code. Its giving me a error from: `Dim browservalue = (GeckoWebBrowser1.Width - GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollWidth)` The error is: https://pastebin.com/hiJ89ERL To note, i never received this error when i used the normal main thread, only now since im multithreading its throwing that error. Any ideas? Sorry for the hassle, iv been at this all morning and its wrecking my head! xD

Comment: I haven't used GeckoFX, but it seems the error is created while casting Width. Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7947162

Comment: So its an issue retrieving the value from the width? I tried using `Document.ActiveElement` this morning as thats where i obtainted how to pull widths but it only pulled from what was active. Which when i used body, it worked no matter what. Its strange cause my code works without it being on a thread. If i put it on the domclick, it fires and operates perfectly? Is there something that can be done with this thread to allow it to work? As it works when its not on another thread.

Comment: If u get the widths in the main thread. Just pass them as parameters to the second thread.

Comment: Great idea, but i need a new set of heights/widths after the elements load in. Because before they load in, the scrollbar doesnt appear because it doesn't need to as there is not enough elements. Thats the purpose of me needing a sleep or a delay in execution. :/

Comment: See my updated answer. To do this activity as per your further requirement, keep the whole Domclick event in a separate method and call it whenever and wherever it is supposed to update the size

Comment: Aaarrrgghh! Never use `Application.DoEvents()` - it is only there for backward compatibility with VB6. It will cause extremely hard to debug re-entrancy issues. If it's part of your solution then it is a bad solution.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for the downvote(and pointing something i already knew, I gave it as an option for him to try). Anyways, If you'd be kind enough do help the OP

Comment: I must say, i appreciate all the help @RahulKurup has put into this as he is the ONLY one i been getting input from. At this stage, i just want this to work correctly. As for your updated answer, i will check now as i was working on another project there. Thanks again!

Comment: @RahulKurup, good news is it works without getting the error! Sad news is, as i stated above. Its doing what i said, if i click on a page that has NO scrollbar.. It saves that with a value of 0, then when i change to a section (tab) WITH a scrollbar then it counts as being without so it keeps the scrollbar, likewise if i go backwords, if i come from a scrollbar to a section without.. It then expands my window. I hope i explained that correctly. Now, if i click on a page with scrollbar it will fix itself but that defeats the purpose! :)

Comment: as i understand from what you say, If a window doesn't have a scrollbar your app's size reduces to lower than what it should be. ?? If thats so, keep a Const Size variable(which can be accessed from anywhere) in the form load event and assign it the window size.. later on you can add a check, whether your form size is reducing than the constant size, if so reset it using this constant

Comment: I dont think i follow, you state `window doesn't have a scrollbar your app's size reduces`. But is it not the browser view that changes when the scrollbar appears / disappears? Not the application width itself? I dont think i follow.

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant Browser* . Oh man, i guess I'm making u more confused :/. And my solution isn't being much help to u. Try googling about it, cuz i guess I'm not gonna be anymore resourceful. Hope somebody wiser than me in stackoverflow helps u out

Answer (score 1):

Try using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (Rx) - just NuGet the bits: "System.Reactive" and "System.Reactive.Windows.Forms" (assuming that you're using Windows Forms).

Then you just do this:

```
Dim subscription As IDisposable = _
    Observable _
        .FromEventPattern(Of EventHandler(Of Gecko.DomMouseEventArgs), Gecko.DomMouseEventArgs)( _
            Sub(h) AddHandler GeckoWebBrowser1.DomClick, h, _
            Sub(h) RemoveHandler GeckoWebBrowser1.DomClick, h) _
        .Select(Function(x) Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))) _
        .Switch() _
        .ObserveOn(Me) _
        .Subscribe(Sub(x) 
            'Code Here
        End Sub)
```

This will wait `1.0` seconds after each `GeckoWebBrowser1.DomClick` before executing `'Code Here`. You can easily change the time waiting in the `Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))` call.

If you want to stop handling the event just call `subscription.Dispose()`.

Comment: When trying to install system.reactive i get `The 'System.Reactive 3.1.1' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60318.667'.` but since i have visual studio 2012, my knowledge is that the max nuget is what i got! There is no updates available. Any idea? Your example above seems exactly what im looking for!

Comment: I looked around and could install an older version, i tried running the code and received: `An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Unable to cast object of type 'applicationname.formname' to type 'System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler'.`

Comment: @irishwill200 - The second error is because you haven't got the `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` bits installed properly. Or you may not have the correct `using` statement at the top of your code. There's an `ObserveOn` overload that takes a `System.Windows.Forms.Control`.

Comment: Could you provide a working example? I fear i perhaps have the above code located wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @irishwill200 - This is a working example. I tested it before posting.

Comment: Sorry, i mean including the subs because you said i dont have the correct `using` statement. Does the above code need to be wrapped in a `using` statement or? As i just had a direct copy / paste (changing the tags to suit mine of course)

Comment: @irishwill200 - Sorry, I meant `using` statements as in `using System.Reactive.Linq;` at the top of your class to reference the right namespaces. That's why I mentioned the `ObserveOn` overload - if you have the right assemblies loaded and the right `using`s then my code works fine.

Comment: Oh right, yes i am already using `Imports System.Reactive.Linq` at the top of the page but still no luck with the code. I thought there was something else i was missing! Anyway, i just recoded my site to include the CSS to hide scrollbars. I didnt want to do that but seeing as im getting no were with these solutions i just changed the css. Thanks for the help though! Hopefully something can jump out and solve this anyway as in the future i would love to get this working.

Comment: @irishwill200 - Sorry, yes, VB is `Imports`. There's another one you need other than `System.Reactive.Linq`. I'll find it.

Comment: @irishwill200 - When you can see the object `System.Reactive.Linq.ControlObservable` then you have the right extension class. So if you're importing `System.Reactive.Linq` and it's not working then it sounds like you haven't properly got `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` installed.

Comment: Hmm i see, well the annoying thing was when trying to install the first time i wasnt able due to me having 2012 version and i needed 2013 + version to install the up to date. So i found a post (cant remember now which one) that had a method which was to install a different plugin (one of the first versions of reactive). Maybe thats why!

Comment: @irishwill200 - The code will work in the earlier versions. You just need to find the right DLL's.

Comment: Well for now i will park this but if you do come across these required DLL's, if you could edit your answer and publish them then that would be a huge help! Because being honest, even if i got these DLL's i wouldnt know were to start with them! Thanks for the help anyway, appreciate it!:)

Comment: @irishwill200 - Try these - https://web.tresorit.com/l#4F6u5aVm5yAGXDuBZ-yEKQ - you've got 30 days to grab them before the link expires.

Comment: Thanks! And dont want to be a noob here but just so i am doing this correctly, what directory (exactly if you can) do i put these files in?

Comment: @irishwill200 - It doesn't matter so long as you reference them in your project.

Comment: Will i need to unistall the nuget package i installed before? I referenced and still used the above code but doesnt seem to make difference, i then unistalled the nuget package and get a `some nuget packages are messing, click restore etc...`

Comment: @irishwill200 - Yes, you need to uninstall the NuGet packages.

Comment: Ok, sorry for long reply! I unistalled the other packages and did: Project -> Add Reference -> Browse -> Selected your folder and added all inside. I then just added your above code under my forms `Public Class form1`. I now get: `'FromEventPattern' is not a member of 'System.Linq.Observable'.`. Now, note.. I dont have any imports as when i try to do `Imports System.Reactive.Linq` i receive a warning stating: `Namespace doesnt contain any public member or cannot be found` <-- Its a long one but did not want to paste it all here. Any ideas? This seems to be a mission and a half!

Comment: @irishwill200 - Sorry, I only found version 1.0. You probably need 2.0 or 1.1. Try starting here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30708

Comment: With that, it is an installer. How would i go about referencing them files?

Comment: @irishwill200 - It installs them to Program Files somewhere. Look for a folder called "Reference Assemblies" or something like that. It might be a few levels deep.

Comment: I am getting nowhere with this! If i got my nuget to the latest version it would be no hassle! I been searching for hours trying find the right downloads but no luck. I might just pass on this and cut my losses!